# What is the difference between 「首都【しゅと】」and 「都【みやこ】」?

Tags: synonyms, nouns

As far as I know, both mean "capital city". Is there a difference in terms of nuance or usage between both words?

よろしくお願いします！

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47930/首都-しゅと-and-都-みやこ